# Busca binária em uma lista sem tamanho fixo

Tags: algoritmo, busca-binária

Há um algoritmo confiável capaz de realizar uma busca binária em uma lista onde não se pode considerar o tamanho (`length` ou `count`) da lista?

Sei que um dos requisitos para uma busca binária é saber este tamanho para dividir a lista, mas no meu caso, não tenho esta lista carregada em memória, ela ficará disponível em um meio externo que receberá apenas o índice do item como parâmetro, retornando o valor contido no índice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou assumir que você está usando alguma forma de *array* e tenha acesso a ele, mesmo que isto seja apenas a representação interna. Caso contrário não vejo como fazer sequer uma busca simples.

Isto pode depender um pouco da linguagem que você está usando. A linguagem precisa ter como descobrir se um índice é válido ou não. O problema é que, até onde eu sei, sempre que você não sabe a quantidade de itens, você também não sabe quando o índice é inválido. Então eu diria que é impossível.

Se conseguir esta informação, você pode ir olhando cada item dobrando o índice se o que está procurando é maior que o valor encontrado naquele índice e vendo se ele ainda é válido ou não (capturando uma exceção ou outra forma que a linguagem permita). Se o o que você procura for menor do que o valor do item encontrado, aí você pega a metade do item atual e o último verificado e não precisa mais se preocupar em verificar se o item é válido. Se já achou um menor, então quando tiver que olhar para um maior deverá considerar a metade entre este item e o maior anteriormente encontrado.

Outra forma é achar o tamanho antes fazendo justamente busca binária. Pode usar a mesma técnica ou fazer a busca binária clássica considerando que o tamanho imaginário seria 2 elevado a 32. É o processo inverso, sempre que der erro vai dividindo o índice por 2, sempre que não der erro pega a metade. Quando não der erro tenta a metade entre esse que não deu erro e o último. Com o tamanho você faz busca binária tradicional.

Sinceramente, embora eu não possa provar, acho que isto é um falso problema justamente pelo requisito de saber quando o índice estoura. Em uma estrutura de dados/linguagem (qualquer *array* ou tipos que usam *array* em sua implementação em Java, C#, etc.) que pode informar se estourou o limite, o tamanho está disponível e é só perguntar. Em C, se o programador tem como saber o tamanho quando monta um *array* ou outra estrutura baseada nele. O que pode acontecer é o código ignorar propositalmente o tamanho. Pra que fazer isto? Se o fizer, acho impossível resolver. Em C, se você jogar fora o tamanho do *array*, você não saberá se acessou um lugar que não devia.

Claro que pode ter maneiras específicas de obter isto se o valor possuir um padrão que seja garantido que não será confundido com outra coisa e ver se ainda está na área do *array*. Mesmo isso, acredito que não dá para garantir isto.

Fora isto, demonstre a real necessidade. Mostre como faria a busca simples neste caso para ver se conseguimos transformar em busca binária.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema utilizando pesquisa exponencial e pesquisa binária juntas, com mais algumas adaptações, deu certo. Quanto a tamanho desconhecido da lista, não teve outra opção a não ser capturar exceções de índices fora dos limites da lista e ir ajustando até conseguir encontrar uma posição válida.

Comment: @MarcosAntonio poste uma resposta com a solução completa. Achei curioso porque para existir exceções de *out of bound* só são possíveis se conhecendo o tamanho da lista :) Você pode ignorar o tamanho mas ele é conhecido.